# Webmin - dhcpd "Stop server" doesnt work on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, webmin

I'm having a problem with webmin since week or so not stopping service correctly.

The other department reported an error while trying to stop DHCP server trough webmin, page doesn't show the service stopped after clicking "Stop Server" button. It still shows buttons "Apply changes" and "Stop server" indicating it's still running. However DHCP server is actually stopped.

I've looked at dhcpd.service configuration:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -user dhcpd -group dhcpd --no-pid
```

Tried to make test VM with CentOS 7 and there it works just fine, despite the "--no-pid" option. Tried to restart webmin service but with no result. The workaround is to click "Apply changes" which restarts the service but this is not what I want.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a known issue,

https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/258

meoso provides the solution,

> With that said, maybe it is simply the fact that there is no pid file by default, thus changing Path to DHCP server PID file to None is the real solution.

Comment: On both machines I have setting `Path to DHCP server PID file : None`